# Can we use "dynamism" as a noun for describing the amount of change and changeability?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, terminology

According to dictionaries, one of the meanings of the word *dynamic* is:

> a system with continuous change

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dynamic
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamic

However, it's used as **adjective**. I'm writing a text in which I need to refer to **continuous change and changeability** and I thought of the word *dynamism*. In other words, I need the noun form of the *dynamic*. However, seems that *dynamism* is not used as that meaning.

For example, instead of **the level of changeability and the amount of change in a system**, I'd like to write **system's dynamism level**.

Can I use *dynamism* in that meaning? If not, what word should I use?

Comment: Dynamic potential?

Answer (score 4):

It's actually defined as a noun in the OED (at least the British English version):

> noun [ mass noun ]
>
> 1 the quality of being characterized by vigorous activity and progress: *the dynamism and strength of the economy.*
>
> • the quality of being dynamic and positive in attitude: *he was known for his dynamism and strong views.*

So, in your example, you could say "the level of dynamism in the system" or "the system's level of dynamism."

Comment: Is there any online reference for that? This solves my problem.

Comment: It's in the [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dynamism?q=dynamism).

Answer (score 3):

Chambers (a *British* English dictionary) has the following definitions:

> **dynamic<sup>[1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=dynamic&title=21st)</sup> *adj***
>   1. full of energy, enthusiasm and new ideas.
>   2. relating to dynamics.
>   **dynamically *adverb***.
>   **ETYMOLOGY**: 19c: from Greek *dynamis* power.
>
> **dynamism<sup>[2](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=dynamism&title=21st)</sup> *noun***
>   limitless energy and enthusiasm.

Those definitions tend to confirm the implications from the OED definitions (quoted in the answer from @somerandomnerdyguy) that *dynamic* and *dynamism* imply *vigorous* change, *full of energy* (which is what I would infer from the words).

But *continuous change and changeability* (as referred to by the OP) need not necessarily be *vigorous*  or *full of energy*: *the level of changeability and the amount of change in a system* may be slow and/or low.

Additionally, *dynamic* and *dynamism* (to me) have a connotation of the change being desired, wanted, a good thing, etc.; whereas, again, the change may be inevitable but not necessarily 'desired'.

So personally, I would be hesitant about using *dynamic* or *dynamism* in the suggested context, but it may be appropriate depending on the 'type' of change being referred to.

Comment: A better alternative may be "ever-changing" which refers more directly to constant change and doesn't have a positive implication.

Answer (score 2):

For that concept I would agree with user afterfake13 to suggest the word **dynamicity**, as "the quality of being dynamic".

It follows on a very widely used and understood pattern for forming abstract nouns from adjectives of Latin or Greek origin: compare "simplicity" and "simple", or "vulnerability" and "vulnerable", etc.

Despite not being listed in mainstream dictionaries, *dynamicity* is widely used and understood, at least in technical contexts: an Internet search turns up almost 200,000 pages that use it.

Moreover, it is not a neologism, because it has been in use for more than a century, as we can see in this issue of the [Chemical News and Journal of Physical Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=4wUAAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA26&dq=dynamicity&hl=it&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q&f=false) of **July, 1867** (second word on the third line).

On the other hand, *dynamism* is usually seen in contexts where it refers to people, and it appears to me to point more to their mindset, or their inclination: as the [Merriam-Webster puts it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamism), it's a "strong desire to make things happen", and it's more like a philosophical theory (just like many other words that end in -ism) than an abstract quality.

Comment: Welcome to ELU and thank you for providing a pleasant surprise in the Late answer review queue with this answer. However there is already a low quality answer mentioning the word. While your answer does give all the things the other is lacking, a short mention of it already being mentioned could further improve it. +1

Comment: Thanks @Helmar for the kudos! I have edited my answer to mention the previous answer suggesting the same word. I would actually have added my comments to that answer, but I didn't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamicity is a derived noun that might be a better word.

Comment: Since "dynamicity", on first blush, appears to be a neologism, you could preemptively defend your answer from downvotes by referencing a dictionary which defines it (i.e. find a dictionary that lists it, quote the defintion, and add a link back to the dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post looking for an answer to the same question about a noun form for dynamic. I like both dynamism and dynamicity but neither really worked for me. I ended up changing the word to **fluidity** and that worked a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **variablility** or perhaps the phrase "the system's level/degree of variability".

Answer (score -1):

Why not stick with *dynamic?* It seems to work fine in your context. Just to clarify, the word *dynamic* is both an adjective and a noun. So saying,

> ... system's dynamic level...

sounds fine.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with 'Dynamics' as a noun and say

The dynamics of the system increases / decreases.

or

The level of dynamics in the system...

Comment: Reading your answer in isolation (because I came across it in the review queue), I have to say that "The dynamics of the system increases" makes no sense at all to me. I can't work out what you're trying to say, so that can't be the best way of phrasing it!